# Jquery Hide Text With Placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, placeholder

I'm trying to hide a text field in jquery by looking for the text field only by its placeholder and nothing else. I'm aiming for something like this:

```
$(look for placeholder with the name credit card number).hide();
```

I don't want to use ids or classes to look for this text field, only the placeholder.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-wrap">
  <table id="credit-card-table">
    <tbody>

      <tr id="credit_card_number_row">
        <td class="field has-float-label">

          <input id="credit_card_n" name="credit_card[cnb]" size="30" value="" placeholder="credit card number" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="19" class="" type="tel">
        <span class="msg"> </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="exp_date_row">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
```

Thank for the help :)

Comment: `$('[placeholder="credit card number"]').hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input[placeholder='credit card number']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="credit_card_n" name="credit_card[cnb]" size="30" value="" placeholder="credit card number" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="19" class="" type="tel"/>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the input in front? As in, how is it different than without the input?

Comment: To be more precise, it is best to write the full Selector. Because there may be a placeholder  with the same title in textarea

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[placeholder="credit card number"]').hide();
```